# Swift 3.0: Store array in UserDefaults for tableView

Tags: arrays, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, swift3

I'm attempting to store an array in UserDefaults yet have had no luck in finding a solution. I have a `struct` and `func` set up that work to store "name" and "description" in an array. The code is as follows...

```
struct task {
    var name = "Untitled"
    var description = "No description available"
}

var tasks = [task]()

func addTask(name: String, description: String) {
    tasks.append(task(name: name, description: description))
}
```

What's the best way to store the data in UserDefaults and add the information to `cell.textLabel?.text` and `cell.detailTextLabel?.text` after a relaunch?

Comment: Should name your struct starting with an uppercase letter. You need to make a class, make it NSCoding compliant and use KeyedArchiever to save the object data

Comment: @LeoDabus Is it not possible to save the array's data with NSUserDefaults?

Comment: You can use UserDeafaults to save Data object from KeyedArchiever

Comment: @LeoDabus ok. I'll have a look into this, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Swift convention to name your structs starting with an uppercase letter. You need to make a class, make it NSCoding compliant and use KeyedArchiever to save the object data

```
class Task: NSObject, NSCoding {
    let name: String
    let desc: String
    required init(name: String, desc: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
    }
    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        coder.encode(desc, forKey: "desc")
    }
    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.name = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String ?? ""
        self.desc = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "desc") as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

---

Testing

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var descField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var tasks: [Task] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "tasks") {
            tasks = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [Task] ?? []
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    @IBAction func addTask(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let name = nameField.text, let desc = descField.text else { return }
        tasks.append(Task(name: name, desc: desc))
        UserDefaults.standard.set(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: tasks) , forKey: "tasks")
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasks.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = tasks[indexPath.row].name + " - " + tasks[indexPath.row].desc
        return cell
    }
}
```